# Retrieving relationships is too slow

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I must be doing something terribly wrong here. I want to retrieve all the relationship nodes with a particular label between two nodes (:User) and (:Movie). My query is

```
match (:User)-[r:HAS_RATED]->(:Movie) return r
```

I have 1 million such relationship nodes. This query takes more than 15 minutes to run on my PC (Win 7, 4GB ram but very low usage by neo4j).

Indexing the relationship nodes is not useful for this case, as the ratings and timestamps of user ratings coincide a lot, and I am not sure I need it anyway here.

How can I run this query faster?
I have alotted 2GB to neo4j in the vmoptions file.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456345/neo4j-cypher-path-finding-slow-in-undirected-graph?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 1):

What connector / driver do you use?

It should be pretty fast, make sure you stream the data away immediately.

What do you want to do with the relationship?

see: http://neo4j.com/blog/export-csv-from-neo4j-curl-cypher-jq/

Comment: i was using the browser console. I had to change the property type of the relationship from string to integer to calculate cosine similarity. I found a workaround by limiting upto 100,000  and running the query again and again until count returned zero.